# "unable to load jna" error on Elasticsearch on Centos

Tags: elasticsearch

What is the solution to this?

New install of elasticsearch 5.4.1 on Centos 6.8

```
[2017-06-15T13:54:19,140][WARN ][o.e.b.Natives            ] unable to load JNA n
ative support library, native methods will be disabled.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/jna--1985354563/jna5608110195315969032.tmp:
 /tmp/jna--1985354563/jna5608110195315969032.tmp: failed to map segment from sha
red object: Operation not permitted
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131
]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java
:947) ~[jna-4.4.0.jar:4.4.0 (b0)]
        at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:922) ~[jna-4
.4.0.jar:4.4.0 (b0)]
        at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:190) ~[jna-4.4.0.jar:4.4.0 (b
0)]
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Natives.<clinit>(Natives.java:45) [elasti
csearch-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.jav
a:105) [elasticsearch-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
```

Comment: According to this github issue, create a homedir for the elastic search user  https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/18272

Comment: @GraysonKent Thank you! I have a /home/elasticsearch dir, owned by user elasticsearch, and the problem persists. The error does not refer to the home dir, so not sure that home dir is the direction of the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this one.

/tmp was mounted noexec.

Updated /etc/fstab to mount /tmp w exec, and this issue is resolved.

Partly discussed here
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/18406

Comment: can you please explain this to me ? i dont understand

Comment: i am nanoing /etc/fstab but i dont know what should i do

Comment: @gagantous This was two years ago, and I do not recall details. I have installed elastic many times since then, no problems.

Comment: no more JNA library error ???

Comment: ever tried to install elastic in Debian ?

Comment: @gagantous Can't speak to Debian. Have never used it.